# Setting variable across multiple if/then statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am using JS to set a total of 7 variables based on conditional statements and looking for the most efficient way to do this.

Currently, there are 16 different conditions that are really grouped into 3 different categories if you will with each category containing multiple conditions but one specific condition that remains the same within the category. In addition, there is one variable that must be consistent across all conditions

Here's an example:

```
if      (myvar === "A" && var1 === 1 && var2 ==="1")
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
else if (myvar === "A" && var1 === 2 && var2 ==="1")
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
else if (myvar === "A" && var1 === 3 && var2 ==="1")
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
else if (myvar === "B" && var1 === 1 && var2 ==="1")
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
else if (myvar === "B" && var1 === 1 && var2 ==="1")
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
else if (myvar === "B" && var1 === 1 && var2 ==="1")
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'd like to only have to set the condition of var2 once and have it apply to all the conditional statements. It would also but better if I could set the value of myvar one time for the first three statements and one time for the last 3.

```
if      (myvar === "A" && var1 === 1 && var2 ==="1")
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
else if (myvar === "A" && var1 === 2 && var2 ==="1")
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
else if (myvar === "A" && var1 === 3 && var2 ==="1")
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
else if (myvar === "B" && var1 === 1 && var2 ==="1")
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
else if (myvar === "B" && var1 === 1 && var2 ==="1")
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
else if (myvar === "B" && var1 === 1 && var2 ==="1")
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
```

Comment: The last 3 conditions are all same. Is that a typo? Should the value of `var1` change to 1,2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap your other conditionals in the repeating conditional:

```
if (var2 === "1")
{
    if (myvar === "A" && var1 === 1)
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
    else if (myvar === "A" && var1 === 2)
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
    else if (myvar === "A" && var1 === 3)
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
    else if (myvar === "B" && var1 === 1)
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
    else if (myvar === "B" && var1 === 1)
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
    else if (myvar === "B" && var1 === 1)
    {
        setVar = "Value";
    }
}
```

Repeat this as necessary for your other overlapping conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Put the control variable in a wrapping if statement, then use a switch statement on the variable with the most variations:

```
if(var2 === "1")
{
    switch(var1)
    {
       case 1:
          if(myvar === "A"){
             setVar = "Value";
          }else if (myvar === "B"){
             setVar = "Value";
          }
          break;

       case 2:
          if(myvar === "A"){
             setVar = "Value";
          }else if (myvar === "B"){
             setVar = "Value";
          }
          break;

       case 3:
          if(myvar === "A"){
             setVar = "Value";
          }else if (myvar === "B"){
             setVar = "Value";
          }
          break;
    }
}
```

You can further compress this statement by moving the `myvar` check into ternary operators, but I only recommend that if there are exactly two variations:

```
if(var2 === "1")
{
    switch(var1)
    {
       case 1:
          setVar = myvar === "A" ? "Value" : "Value";
          break;

       case 2:
          setVar = myvar === "A" ? "Value" : "Value";
          break;

       case 3:
          setVar = myvar === "A" ? "Value" : "Value";
          break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You ca't use a ternary operator here - myvar != A is not === B!

Comment: @LTPCGO that's why I specifically said `I only recommend that if there are exactly two variations`

Comment: even if there are two *expected* variations it's not a good idea without extra code; perhaps with a prefix line like `if(myvar != "A" && myvar != "B") myvar = "B";` but that's not going to make the code any clearer

Comment: @LTPCGO you could just move the check into a wrapper clause, e.g. `if(myvar === "A" || myvar === "B")`. Throw an error if it returns false.